# Error! TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Enable color camera

Tags: android, camera, google-project-tango, tango

I am trying to connect to the tango device and open the camera and just stream the video, i have written the code but it gives me error

"TangoErrorType TangoService_connect(void*, TangoConfig): Enable color camera"

Here is the code,

public class Main_activity extends Activity {

```
private static final String TAG = Main_activity.class.getSimpleName();
private Tango mTango;
private TangoConfig mConfig;
public TangoCameraPreview camera;
private boolean mIsTangoServiceConnected;
private boolean isConnected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);

    // Instantiate Tango client
    mTango = new Tango(this);

    //Setting up the Tango Configuration
    mConfig = new TangoConfig();
    mConfig = mTango.getConfig(mConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_CURRENT);
    mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_MOTIONTRACKING, true);
    mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
    mConfig.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORCAMERA, true);
    camera = new TangoCameraPreview(this);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //lock the Tango Configuration and reconnect to the service each time
    //when the app is brought to the foreground

    super.onResume();
    if(!mIsTangoServiceConnected){

        startActivityForResult(
                Tango.getRequestPermissionIntent(Tango.PERMISSIONTYPE_MOTION_TRACKING),
                Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE);
    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    //check which request we're responding
    if(requestCode == Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "This app requires Motion Tracking permission!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        try{
            setTangoListeners();
            camera.connectToTangoCamera(mTango,0);
            startcamerapreview();
        }
        catch(TangoErrorException e){

            Toast.makeText(this, "Tango Error! Restart the app!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            mTango.connect(mConfig);
            mIsTangoServiceConnected = true;

        } catch (TangoOutOfDateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Tango Service out of date!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        catch (TangoErrorException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Tango Error! Restart the app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    try {
        mTango.disconnect();
        mIsTangoServiceConnected = false;
    } catch (TangoErrorException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tango Error!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void setTangoListeners(){
    Log.i(TAG,"Just the basic exmaple");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Running on the Tango Device, JJ branch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void startcamerapreview(){

    camera.connectToTangoCamera(mTango, TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_RGBIR);
    isConnected=true;

    ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs = new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();
    mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new OnTangoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose) {
            // We are not using OnPoseAvailable for this app
        }


        @Override
        public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {

            // Check if the frame available is for the camera we want and
            // update its frame on the camera preview.
            if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_RGBIR) {
                camera.onFrameAvailable();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData xyzIj) {
            // We are not using OnPoseAvailable for this app
        }

        @Override
        public void onTangoEvent(TangoEvent event) {
            // We are not using OnPoseAvailable for this app
        }

        public void onPointCloudAvailable(TangoPointCloudData tpcd){

        }
    });
}// StartCameraPreview
```

}

My Goal is to initialize camera in tango and open the camera app.
Thanks in advance